# Webpack host redirecting requests to google app engine backend

Tags: angular, google-app-engine, proxy, angular-cli, google-app-engine-python

I am trying to use Angular2 CLI to help scaffold and create my angular 2 project. This includes a great setup for testing suite, webpack, etc.

I also have developed an API in Python on Google App Engine. Unfortunately, if I solely use GAE to host my front end, I lose some of the niceness of webpack (auto-detect, reload, unit testing).

I tried to use a proxy config to redirect my requests to my backend.

```
{
  "/api" :{
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "loglevel": "debug"
  },
  "/_ah" :{
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "loglevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

I reference the proxy config with `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json`.
This works for requests that I have defined using webapp2 directly. Those requests are held at the /api level.

This fails however for the requests I have defined behind /_ah, which I use the endpoints library to define.

```
ModuleDoesNotExistError('localhost:4200',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 1302, in communicate
    req.respond()
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 831, in respond
    self.server.gateway(self).respond()
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy/cherrypy/wsgiserver/wsgiserver2.py", line 2117, in respond
    for chunk in response:
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/endpoints/endpoints_server.py", line 121, in __call__
yield self.dispatch(request, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/endpoints/endpoints_server.py", line 151, in dispatch
return self.call_spi(request, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/endpoints/endpoints_server.py", line 324, in call_spi
spi_request.source_ip)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/dispatcher.py", line 639, in add_request
headers_dict['Host'], urlparse.urlsplit(relative_url).path)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/dispatcher.py", line 713, in _resolve_target
raise request_info.ModuleDoesNotExistError(hostname)
ModuleDoesNotExistError: localhost:4200
```

I am hoping there is a configuration that I can setup with GAE, to allow the requests from port 4200. Or some other way, that I can keep the value of angular cli / webpack combo, while hosting the local api with GAE.

---

**UPDATE**

I did something pretty gross to get it to work, but I still feel like I am missing a configuration file.

My hack to get it to work was updating an app server py file:
`"/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/dispatcher.py"`

I changed line 685 to this hard coded option `if not hostname or hostname == default_address or hostname == 'localhost:4200':`

This now, no longer throws an error, but is terrible fix. Any help would be appreciated, so I can back this out, and use the tool properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting changeOrigin to true in your proxy.config. As in:

```
"/_ah" : {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "loglevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! I backed out my change and this works! I would upvote if I had more rep, but thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks for this. I ran into this issue using the deferred (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred) library on my AppEngine project, and this solved the issue. Cheers!